# How to reach to a chartjs chart's value?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chartjs line chart that has multiple lines like that;[image]

I have been trying to add a date-time selector but I am not able to update my chart because I don't get how to reach the datas of my chart. Here is my chart decleration;

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: time1, time2,
            datasets: [
                {
                label: 'Temperature - 1',
                data: temp1,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'red',
                borderWidth: 3
            },
            {
                label: 'Temperature - 2',
                data: temp2,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'purple',
                borderWidth: 3
            },
            {
                label: 'Humidity - 1',
                data: hum1,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'green',
                borderWidth: 3
            },
            {
                label: 'Humidity - 2',
                data: hum2,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'yellow',
                borderWidth: 3
            }]
        },
        options: {
            elements: {
                line: {
                    tension: 0
                }
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    title: "Temperature/Humidity",
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    min: 10,
                    max: 60
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

time1, time2, temp1, temp2, hum1, hum2 are all array. When I want to update the chart using `chart.update()` function that I read at [its own documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/developers/updates.html), as I said I don't get it how to reach to data arrays like temp1, temp2.
Something like `myChart.data.datasets.data` would not work, making them like json;

```
{first_data:{
            label: 'Temperature - 1',
            data: temp1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 3
        }},
```

Doesn't work also, how can I reach to temp1 for example?

**SOLUTION:**

Because of my carelessness I had asked a nonsense question. Because of myChart.data.datasets is an object, I am able to reach to temp1 like `myChart.data.datasets[0].data`, sorry everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to target the specific dataset you want to get the data from so to get the data of the `Temperature - 1` dataset you will need to target it like this: `myChart.data.datasets[0].data`

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);

console.log(myChart.data.datasets[0].label)
console.log(myChart.data.datasets[0].data)
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: ooowwww stupid me, the datasets is an object also... What a stupid question lol. Thank you so much, I was not be aware of it :/

Comment: np man, can happen, glad you learned from it